# Can't capture result of then part of a typescript method

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm calling a function `createUser(....)` like below

```
let response=  this.createUser(email,false,"+"+phoneNumber,password,displayName,false);
```

and this is the function.

```
createUser(email:string, emailVerified:boolean, phoneNumber:string, password:string, displayName:string, disabled:boolean ) {
    admin.createUser({
        email: email,
      emailVerified: emailVerified,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      password: password,
      displayName: displayName,
      disabled: disabled
     })
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
        return Promise.resolve(userRecord);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
        return Promise.reject;
     });
     return null;
 }
```

But I want to capture the result returned by `createUser` which is being created under `then` part of that method.
How can I capture its result, which is `async` call in `response` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to return inside the `createUser` function like this:

```
// ...
function createUser( /*params omitted*/ ) {
  return admin.createUser({ // <-- notice the return here
      // ...
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      //...
      return Promise.resolve(userRecord);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // ... remember return the error data too
    });
  // return null;
}
// ...
```

Now you can get the result like this:

1.Inside an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) using `await`:

```
async function getValue() {
  let response = await this.createUser( /*params*/ );
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("sample data after 1 second");
    }, 1000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(x);
}
f1();
```

2.Inside a regular function using a callback inside `then` expression (from [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)):

```
function getValue() {
  this.createUser( /*params*/ ).then(function(userRecord) {
    let response = userRecord;
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("sample data after 1 second");
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function f1() {
  resolveAfter2Seconds(10).then(function(sampleData) {
     console.log(sampleData);
  });
}

f1();
```

Comment: Its prompting an error that my await expression is only allowed within an async function at: let response =  await this.createUser(/*params*/);

Comment: Thanks...this saved my time :)